# add mark into sentence if some word in sentence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like below

| sentence | key phase |
| --- | --- |
| I love Python | love Python |
| I love Coding | love Coding |

I want to add the mark $ and /$ in the head and tail of the key phase like below.

| sentence | key phase |
| --- | --- |
| I $love Python/$ | love Python |
| I $love Coding/$ | love Coding |

Any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried so far? It's helpful for others to help you debug.

This may be a starting point to help though

```
def transform_string(input_string, key_phrase):
    return input_string.replace(key_phrase, f"${key_phrase}/$")

input_string = "I love Python"
key_phrase = "love Python"

transformed_string = transform_string(input_string, key_phrase)
print(transformed_string)
```

Comment: Thx! I just thought add the mark but the replace method is very fit for my case!